# How to change EMPTY > Image dimensions in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, image, dimensions

I am looking to add a Geo-reference Satellite image into blender via `IMAGE > BACKGROUND`. After adding the image, I wanted to change the dimension of the image but couldn't find `DIMENSIONS` section on Blender 2.8. On previous Blender 2.79, there is `Dimensions` option available as image below:

[image: Dimension section on Blender 2.79]

How to make it work in Blender 2.8?

Comment: when you add an image as a background it fills the whole background, being scaled as needed by the software. If you really want control over scaling, add the image as a texture in a background texture node connected to the world's node. And connect a texture coordinate > generated to a mapping node, then the mapping node to the image texture.

Comment: You mean these steps? `1.Image Texture`node, `2. Background` node, `3. World Output` node?

Comment: Yes ! Unless you are trying to model over a picture.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to make the image as my reference. I tried as you said but couldn't see any image over there.

Comment: That's because it'll only appear on render. Sorry for waisting your time, the answer you'r looking out is below

Comment: Below? I couldn't find anything here.

Comment: There was actually an answer before it was removed.